# Passing a variable dynamically via macros within a model definition

Tags: dbt

within the definition of a template, I would like to pass the name dynamically as follows:

```
version: 1

vars:
  target_prefix: "{{ get_env.get_target_prefix(profile) }}"

sources:
  - name: curated_views
    tables:
      - name: "{{ target_prefix }}xdb06__EVDA_TETSRY_ADE_SER"
```

The macros that I created is this (macros/get_env.sql):

```
{% macro get_target_prefix(profile) %}
  {% if profile.target == 'dev' %}
    g
  {% elif profile.target == 'test' %}
    x2
  {% else %}
    {% raise "Unknown target value: " + profile.target %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

This macros go to the file defined in dbt/profiles.yml and check if the variables target have the value "test/dev".
I was asking if there is a better way to do this, also bc this do not work